# How has my profit margin risen?

Tags: profits

I quote the first few paras. of [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/7smiok/eli5_what_are_people_in_the_stock_exchange/dt5y625/):

> [1.] Imagine you had a business selling lollipops at school. Since you can
>   buy a bag of 100 for \$10, you can sell them for 25¢ a piece for a
>   profit.
>
> [2.] But you don't have \$10. But there is profit to be made for all if
>   people give you the money. So you ask your friends to **invest**. They
>   each give you \$1 and you give them (and yourself) some **stock** in
>   the **venture** - a promise to split the profit. You guys buy a bag,
>   and in one week, you sell all your lollipops for 25¢ each.
>
> [3.] So now you have 0 lollipops and 25¢ x 100 = \$25 Awesome!  Maybe you
>   pay yourself a market rate for your job in the venture as salesman
>   (you're also an employee since you sold the pops) - say \$5 So you have
>   \$20 to split 10 ways. Everybody makes \$2 from their \$1 investment -
>   everybody wins. you could pay them back their \$1 investment and
>   another \$1 profit - this extra is called a **dividend**.
>
> [4.] Now, would your investors go in again next week? Sure! You're doubling
>   their money. And you ran out of lollipops right? So maybe get everyone
>   together to vote and we all agree at a **shareholder meeting** to skip
>   the dividend and turn the venture into a **business** that reinvests
>   the profit into 2 bags of lollipops and make money even faster.
>
> [5.] Next week you sell out again. Since you're just one sales guy, you
>   still only cost \$5 and your **profit margin** has risen. You can now
>   buy 4.5 bags of lollipops each week. Your business is growing!

See para. 5:

6. how has my profit margin risen? The profit is the same in the sales in 1 and 4?
7. why can I "buy 4.5 bags of lollipops each week"? Is the author just postulating this? Or does this follow from my 2 sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin with 1 bag was \$25 (revenue) / \$15 (labor + materials), or ~166%. The margin with 2 bags, assuming no additional labor costs, is \$50/$25, or 200%.

When this business plans out expenditures on labor and materials for the third time around, it has \$50 cash, enough to pay $5 for labor and up to of 4.5 bags of candy.